# python, iterate through a list in a nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to generate from random variables for an inserting in a database but I'm always getting the same string when i try to iterate thru the widgetname list. I'm getting gadget all the 5 iterations. How do i get different string?

output Im getting

```
wd name: gadget
91
9
wd name: gadget
87
1
wd name: gadget
41
10
wd name: gadget
16
10
wd name: gadget
50
4
```

my code:

```
widgetname=['sprocket', 'gizmo', 'gadget']
price=0
design_date='2010-02-10'
version=0
design_comment='design comment goes here'

count = 0
while (count < 5):
    count += 1
    for widget in widgetname:
        widget_name = widget
    for i in range(count):
        price=random.randint(1.0, 100.0)
    for j in range(count):
        version=random.randint(1.0, 10.0)

    print('wd name: '+widget_name)
    print(price)
    print(version)
```

Comment: your `for` loops are not nested, they're sequential

Comment: What's the point of your inner loops anyways? All three of them create 5 values but only store the last. Each loop completes completely before the next one starts. Throw some print statements into the loops to understand what your code does.

Comment: Remove: `for i in range(count):` and `for j in range(count):`, and indent the print statements.

Comment: How many output groups do you actually want? 5? or 5x5x5x5 = 625?

Comment: If you're trying to get a random widget, you don't need a `for` loop but `random.choice`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, random.choice worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all the loops, just the outer one, see the snippet below

```
for count in range(5):
    widget_name = random.choice(widgetname)   
    price=random.randint(1, 100)
    version=random.randint(1, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you, its so simple, was unnecessarily complicating it.